# SQL - Using Subquery inside a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me write a sql query that will produce the number of customers in each city sorted from highest to lowest in the table below. Include only the cities that have more than average number of customers across all cities in that state.

Table content:
Customer id, Customer Name, Customer State, Customer City

I do not understand how to bring the average in the query filter

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Code removed, the image is a sample of how the table looks like

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: `I do not understand how to bring the average in the query filter` you need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in your query. This is a very introductory question, and you won't learn much unless you try something first. Once you have tried a query and get stuck then show us the query in your next question

Answer (score 0):

I just guessing the schema of the tables. But probably you can check the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Customer City], 
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Customers] 
FROM 
    [Customers] 
GROUP BY 
    [Customer State], 
    [Customer City] 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > (SELECT AVG(C) FROM 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM [Customers] 
            GROUP BY [Customer State], [Customer City]) AS T) 
ORDER BY 
    [Number of Customers] DESC
```